# How to fix scaling of a Java-based application on a high DPI display in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, swing, scaling, highdpi

I just switched to Java 11 (AdoptOpenJDK) so that my Java Swing application looks OK on high DPI displays at different system scaling settings.

It works OK on Windows. Regardless of the scaling value configured on the system, Java automatically detects it and uses it to scale the GUI accordingly.

However, on Linux the GUI does not consider the system scaling, and thus, it looks tiny on high-DPI displays.

After reading some posts here, I found I can indicate Java what scaling value to use. For example, if system scaling is 200%, then I can add the following command line argument to the java command used to launch the application.

`-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.0`

The GUI looks fine on Linux when I add the above command line option.

I also read I can set the GDK_SCALE environment variable.

However, I'd like to find a better solution. Ideally, one where I don't need to specify the scaling value to use. Does anybody know if this is possible?

If the above is not possible, then I guess my next step will be to come up with a command in Linux that returns what the current system scaling value is and use it to set the `sun.java2d.uiScale` option.

Comment: It looks like it is related to this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8260270

Comment: This is not a java problem. It is a problem of "the" linux display manager. I have also a high dpi display, that caused issues in the size of guis. Cos I only use xorg, I made it with `Xft.dpi: 140` in the `.Xresources` (xrandr did not work)     Former issues with hdpi should be solved https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/263

Comment: It is a java problem -  I have yet to see a java program that reacts to Xft.dpi, while almost every other application does the right thing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a set of pre made scales and math scaling for all gui components, you could use borderlayout to size components and gridbaglayout to position components then only fonts and images require math resize.

graphicsdevice and graphicsenvironment classes
Re: java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration. getBounds()

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party tool named [**jHiccup**](https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup). It can automatically detects the scaling value of the system. Then, using it you can fix the GUI.

For example,

***To get the scaling value***

```
double dpiScaling = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution() / 96.0;
```

***Set the scaling factor***

```
JHiccup.setScaleFactor(dpiScaling);
```

You can check out the **jHiccup**'s documentation.

Reference - https://docs.azul.com/prime/jHiccup

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? As far as I can tell, JHiccup refers to a project that tracks stalls in a running Java application. I see nothing that refers to screen scaling there, as useful as that might be.

Answer (score -4):

You can try this one:

```
-Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true
```

As the official documentation says:

> Setting this flag to true enables hardware-accelerated scaling if the DirectDraw/Direct3D pipeline is in use. DirectDraw/Direct3D hardware scaling is disabled by default to avoid rendering artifacts in existing applications.

For more information, you can see the official [Oracle documentation about system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html).

Comment: Regardless of this helping answer the question, please provide more context on what this does and how this solves the problem at hand. Simply posting a piece of code without explanation will create more confusion.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've added a description with link to Oracle documentation, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: This does not work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: This refers to Java 7 documentation, which is not applicable to the situation the question is about.

Comment: DirectDraw/Direct3D are Windows-specific things, so this won't work on Linux (the option is also listed under _"System Properties for Microsoft Windows Platforms"_).